# I want to freeze a page flip animation midway. Is this possible with UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to get a flip animation like what the Maps App has (similar example here:http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/fdcurlviewcontrol) so that the previous page is still visible and curled up (or to the side).

The animation for iBooks (UIPageViewController) would be perfect if I could freeze the animation part-way through. I know you can flip pages through code. Is there a way to freeze the animation through code? Maybe mimic user touch?

Is there a third party library that could do this? I looked at PaperStack but it is not ready for commercial use and I could not find any freezing functionality either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a third party library: https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl#concepts
It allows you to customize the curl of the page and stop it at any point. It's an amazing class. Thank you xissburg!